# Determine Garbage collector type from jconsole/jvisualvm?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jconsole, jvisualvm

Is there a way I can find GC type (parallel or CMS or G1 ) from jnconsole or jvisualvm? In my case, I see  below related info:

```
Garbage Collector : Name='PS MarkSweep'....
Garbage Collector : Name='PS Scavenge'....
```

When I use the command `-XX: +PrintCommandLineFlags` it displays `-XX:+UseParallelGC`, so it confirms its parallel GC collector(though I though its CMS because of name `PS MarkSweep` in jconsole/jvisualvm) .

What will be the GC collector values for CMS and G1?

Answer (score 2):

**Parallel Garbage collector:** `-XX:+UseParallelGC` (jvm option to use this collector, though this is default as of java 8)

Under jconsole/jvisualvm

```
Name = 'PS Scavenge', ... for (Minor Collection)
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'PS MarkSweep', for (Major Collection)
```

**CMS Garbage collector:** `-XX:+UseParNewGC` (jvm option to use this collector)

Under jconsole/jvisualvm

```
Name = 'ParNew', ... for (Minor Collection)
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'MarkSweepCompact', for (Major Collection)
```

**G1 Garbage collector:** `-XX:+UseG1GC` (jvm option to use this collector)

Under jconsole/jvisualvm

```
Name = 'G1 Young Generation', ... for (Minor Collection)
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'G1 Old Generation', for (Major Collection)
```

**Without jconsole/jvisualvm:-** you can juse `-XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags` jvm option to see GC type details on console